# open ai api issue when I use dall-e api for generate image. getting "invalid request error" and image_url is not generating with the dalle 3

Tags: wordpress, openai-api

im trying this to generate the content with images using dall-e and chatgpt api's so create a acticle and post it to the wordpress site. so while compiling the code i faced this below issue

{
"error": {
"code": null,
"message": "Additional properties are not allowed ('max_tokens', 'messages' were unexpected)",
"param": null,
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}

dalle response is:
{
"error": {
"code": null,
"message": "[None] is not of type 'string' - 'prompt'",
"param": null,
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}

image_url:  []
Empty image URLs generated.
Error: 'image_urls' is None.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\1new-article-working-without-image.py", line 200, in 
post_id = post_to_wordpress_with_images(article_title, article_content, image_urls)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\1new-article-working-without-image.py", line 171, in post_to_wordpress_with_images
for i, image_url in enumerate(image_urls):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

im expecting the code to post the generated content with images from the chatgpt and dall-e api and post it to the wordpress site